# StaleObjectstateException row was updated or deleted by

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, exception, staleobjectstate

I am getting this exception in a controller of a web application based on spring framework using hibernate. I have tried many ways to counter this but could not resolve it.

In the controller's method, `handleRequestInternal`, there are calls made to the database mainly for 'read', unless its a submit action. 
I have been using, Spring's Session but moved to `getHibernateTemplate()` and the problem still remains.

basically, this the second call to the database throws this exception. That is:

1) `getEquipmentsByNumber(number)`  { firstly an equipment is fetched from the DB based on the 'number', which has a list of properties and each property has a list of values. I loop through those values (primitive objects Strings) to read in to variables)

2) `getMaterialById(id)` {fetches materials based on id}

I do understand that the second call, most probably, is making the session to "flush", but  I am only 'reading' objects, then why does the second call throws the stale object state exception on the Equipment property if there is nothing changed?

I cannot clear the cache after the call since it causes LazyExceptions on objects that I pass to the view.

I have read this:
https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=996355&start=0
but could not solve the problem based on the suggestions provided.

How can I solve this issue? Any ideas and thoughts are appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
What I just tested is that in the function `getEquipmentsByNumber()` after reading the variables from list of properties, I do this: `getHibernateTemplate().flush();` and now the exception is on this line rather then the call to fetch material (that is `getMaterialById(id)`).

**UPDATE:**
Before explicitly calling flush, I am removing the object from session cache so that no stale object remains in the cache.

```
getHibernateTemplate().evict(equipment);
getHibernateTemplate().flush();
```

OK, so now the problem has moved to the next fetch from DB after I did this. I suppose I have to label the methods as synchronized and evict the Objects as soon as I am finished reading their contents! it doesn't sound very good.

**UPDATE:**
Made the `handleRequestInternal` method "synchronized". The error disappeared. Ofcourse, not the best solution, but what to do!
Tried in `handleRequestInternal` to close the current session and open a new one. But it would cause other parts of the app not to work properly. Tried to use `ThreadLocal` that did not work either.

Comment: if you could post the code for the method that is throwing the exception I will look at it further.  Sounds kind of fishy

Answer (score 6):

You're mis-using Hibernate in some way that causes it to think you're *updating* or *deleting* objects from the database.

That's why calling `flush()` is throwing an exception.

One possibility:  **you're incorrectly "sharing" Session or Entities, via member field(s) of your servlet or controller**. This is the main reason 'synchronized' would change your error symptoms..  Short solution: don't ever do this.  Sessions and Entities shouldn't & don't work this way -- each Request should get processed independently.

Another possibility:  **`unsaved-value` defaults to 0 for "int" PK fields**.  You may be able to type these as "Integer" instead, if you really want to use 0 as a valid PK value.

Third suggestion:   **use Hibernate Session explicitly, learn to write simple correct code that works**, then load the Java source for Hibernate/ Spring libraries so you can read & understand what these libraries are actually doing for you.

Answer (score 3):

I also have been struggling with this exception, but when it continued to recur even when I put a lock on the object (and in a test environment, where I knew I was the only process touching the object), I decided to give the parenthetical in the stack trace its due consideration.

> org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by
>   another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):
>   [com.rc.model.mexp.MerchantAccount#59132]

In our case it turned out that the mapping was wrong; we had `type="text"` in the mapping for one field that was a mediumtext type in the database, and it seems that Hibernate really hates that, at least under certain circumstances. We removed the type specification altogether from the mapping for this field, and the problem was resolved.

Now the weird thing is that in our production environment, with the supposedly problematic mapping in place, we do NOT get this exception. Does anybody have any idea why this might be? We are using the same version of MySQL - "5.0.22-log" (I don't know what the "-log" means) - in dev and production envs.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 possibilities (as I do not know exactly, which kind of hibernate session handling you are using). Add one after another and test:

Use bi-directional mapping with `inverse=true` between parent object and child object, so the change in parent or child will get propagate to the other end of relation properly.

Add support for **Optimistic Locking** using `TimeStamp` or `Version` column

Use **join query** to fetch the whole object graph [ parent+children] together to avoid the second call altogether.

**Lastly, if and only if nothing works:**
Load the parent again by `Id` (you have that already) and populate modified data then update.

Life will be good!  :)

Comment: I think the suggestion of using inverse is probably confusing in context of propagation of changes from parent to child. For this the actual behavior to configure is "cascade". Inverse as a concept is orthogonal to cascading

Answer (score 1):

This problem was something that I had experienced and was quite frustrating, although there has to be something a little odd going on in your DAO/Hibernate calls, because if you're doing a lookup by ID there is no reason to get a stale state, since that is just a simple lookup for an object.

First, make sure all your methods are annotated with `@Transaction(required=true) // you'll have to look up the exact syntax`

However, this exception is usually thrown when you try to make changes to an object that has been detached from the session it was retrieved from.  The solution to this is often not simple and would require more code posted so we can see exactly what is going on; my general suggestion would be to create a `@Service` that performs these kinds of things within a single transaction

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
What I just tested is that in the function getEquipmentsByNumber after reading the variables from list of properties, I do this:
getHibernateTemplate().flush(); and now the exception is on this line rather then the call to fetch material (that is getMaterialById(id))

I am not using annotations since I am not very much familiar with it.